# How to merge multiple dataframes into a new dataframe where each dataframe becomes a new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a reoccurring situation where I have multiple files (or excel sheets) with data in 8 rows and 12 columns, each file being some attribute or measurement but the indices line up across all files.
Example: In row 5 column 8 for each file is a new attribute for the same sample.
What I want to make is one data frame where each row is a sample and all the columns are its attributes for further analysis from these many files.

Currently, I can solve this two ways:

1. Slow and inefficient: Iterate over one dataframe and then get the values for each other dataframe at the same index/column, and build a new dataframe row by row.
2. I can unstack a dataframe and then drop the generated unwanted columns, then merge all unstacked dataframes.  This also seems inefficient but is much faster than method 1.
   Small example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Q_Rows', index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Q_Columns', index_col=0)
df3 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Q_Wells', index_col=0)
df1 = df1.unstack().reset_index()
df1 = df1.rename(columns ={0:'Rows'})
df1 = df1[df1.columns.drop(list(df1.filter(regex='level')))]
df2 = df2.unstack().reset_index()
df2 = df2.rename(columns ={0:'Columns'})
df2 = df2[df2.columns.drop(list(df2.filter(regex='level')))]
df3 = df3.unstack().reset_index()
df3 = df3.rename(columns ={0:'Wells'})
df3 = df3[df3.columns.drop(list(df3.filter(regex='level')))]
df3
>   Wells
0   A01
1   B01
2   C01
3   D01
4   E01
... ...
91  D12
92  E12
93  F12
94  G12
95  H12

df = df1.merge(df2, right_index=True, left_index=True, how='outer')
df = df.merge(df3, right_index=True, left_index=True, how='outer')
df
  Rows  Columns Wells
0   A   1   A01
1   B   1   B01
2   C   1   C01
3   D   1   D01
4   E   1   E01
... ... ... ...
91  D   12  D12
92  E   12  E12
93  F   12  F12
94  G   12  G12
95  H   12  H12
```

These methods "work", but my question is: is there a built-in pandas method or a more elegant solution that does this kind of column-based merging/transposing already?  Or are there any more elegant suggestions?
Thank you.